# is it conflicting for multiple users on one backend server websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, backend

I'm planning on building some backend logic on a server for personal use. Its connected to a websocket from another server and I've set code to handle data from that socket. I'm still fairly new to using websockets so the whole concept is still a little foreign to me.

If I allowed more users to use that backend and the websocket has specific logic running wouldn't it be conflicted by multiple users? Or would each user have their own instance of the script running?

Does it make any sense of what I'm trying to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I allowed more users to use that backend and the websocket has specific logic running wouldn't it be conflicted by multiple users? Or would each user have their own instance of the script running?

In node.js, there is only one copy of the script running (unless you use something like clustering to run a copy of the script for each core, which it does not sound like you are asking about).  So, if you have multiple webSocket connections to the same server, they will all be running in the same server code with the same variables, etc...  This is how node.js works.  One running Javascript engine and one code base serves many connections.

node.js is an event-driven system so it will serve an incoming event from one webSocket, then return control back to the Javascript system and serve the next event in the event queue and so on.  Whenever a request handler calls some asynchronous operation and waits for a response, that is an opportunity for another event to be pulled from the incoming event queue and another request handler can run.  In this way, multiple requests handlers can be interleaved with all making progress toward completion, even though there is only one single thread of Javascript running.

What this architecture generally means is that you never want to put request-specific state in the global or module scope because those scopes are shared by all request handlers.  Instead, the state should be in the request-specific scope or in a session that is bound to that particular user.

> Is it conflicting for multiple users on one backend server websockets

No, it will not conflict if you write your server code properly.  Yes, it will conflict if you write your server code wrongly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. So as it stands now the logic I built would be conflicting to other users.

Comment: @Chresna - It depends entirely upon how you wrote the code and what it does and you didn't show us any code so we can't say for sure one way or the other.  I can say that it is not difficult to use proper design principles to write a server that can happily serve thousands of users.